# How to handle GroupUserAdding event in power automate or powerapps

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms

We are migrating Sharepoint farm solution to SP Online.

In solution we have GroupUserAdding receiver. In event receiver, i need to validate user first with some condition before adding to group.  I am not able to find any GroupUserAdding regarding trigger in power automate or in powerapps.

Please help any feasibility or workaround to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Power Apps and Power Automate you don't need to use event receivers. And you can't.

Instead, you need to organize the app logic like so:

- When button is cllicked, validate everything that needs to be validated.
- If validation was passed - continue adding users to the group.
- If validation failed - do nothing.

That's it - no need for any event receivers.